# Does the "holomorphic spheres-to-continuous spheres" forgetful function respect the mixed Hodge structures on homotopy groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, hodge-structure

For each smooth, projective, complex variety $X$ that is simply connected, John Morgan constructed a natural mixed Hodge structure on the homotopy group $\pi_k(X,x)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$.  This was extended to (possibly singular) quasi-projective varieties independently by Hain, by Deligne, and by Navarro Aznar.  For <del>any</del> the basepoint connected component of the double loop space $\Omega^2 X_0\sim [(S^2,0),(X,x)]_0$, each homotopy group $\pi_k(\Omega^2 X_0)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is canonically isomorphic to $\pi_{k+2}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$, $k>0$. Thus these also have natural mixed Hodge structures.

Grothendieck constructed a Hom scheme $$H=\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}((\mathbb{CP}^1,0),(X,x))$$ parameterizing algebraic maps (i.e., holomorphic maps in case $X$ is projective).  Each quasi-compact, open and closed subset $H_\beta$ of the Hom scheme is quasi-projective.  Assuming that $H_\beta$ is connected, there is a well-defined homotopy class of maps $$\Phi_{\beta}:H_\beta \to \Omega^2 X_0,$$ that associates to each holomorphic map from $\mathbb{CP}^1 = S^2$ the underlying continuous map.  There are associated pushforward maps on homotopy groups, $$\Phi_{k,\beta}: \pi_k(H_\beta)\otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \pi_{k+2}(X,x)\otimes \mathbb{Q}.$$  Assume now that $H_\beta$ is simply connected so that the groups $\pi_k(H_\beta)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ have mixed Hodge structures. (There are many cases of $X$ where the associated spaces $H_\beta$ are connected and simply connected.  Also, with no hypothesis on $H_\beta$, one can also ask about compatibility with mixed Hodge structures of the induced homomorphism $H_1(H_\beta;\mathbb{Q}) \to \pi_3(X,x)\otimes \mathbb{Q}.$)  Also, as Dan Petersen points out, it is necessary to form the Tate twist of the target, i.e., $\pi_{k+2}(X,x)\otimes \mathbb{Q}(1)$.

**Question**. Is the pushforward map $\Phi_{k,\beta}$ a morphism of mixed Hodge structures?

Of course there are many complex varieties $X$ for which $H$ is empty, and then the answer is trivially yes.  Yet there are many other complex projective manifolds, e.g., Fano manifolds, where the maps $\Phi_{k,\beta}$ are nontrivial.

Comment: What does the subscript 0 mean in $\Omega^2 X_0\sim [(S^2,0),(X,x)]_0$? If it means "basepoint component", then why do you say "for any connected component"? If not, why is the isomorphism between $\pi_k(\Omega^2 X_0)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ and $\pi_{k+2}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ canonical?

Comment: @TomChurch.  You are correct.  I am eliding the issue that the function $\Phi_\beta$ is only well-defined up to homotopy.  There is a canonical function $\Phi_\beta$ to the connected component of $\Omega^2 X$ corresponding to the homotopy class $\beta\in \pi_2(X)$.  The homotopy equivalence of this component with the basepoint component is only well-defined up to homotopy.

Comment: Is it easily seen that there is a continuous $\Phi_\beta$?

Comment: "Is it easily seen that there is a continuous $\Phi_\beta$?"  Certainly $\Phi_\beta$ is *not* continuous for the Zariski topology on $H_\beta$.  It is continuous for the analytic topology on the associated analytic space of $H_\beta$.  Similarly, the notation $\pi_{k+2}(X,x)$ means the homotopy group for the associated analytic space of $X$.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that topology. Is it easy to see? Are the $H_\beta$s actually homeomorphic to subspaces of $\Omega^2X$?

Comment: "Is it easy to see?"  Yes; this is part of adjointness of the space of continuous functions with the compact-open topology.  Let $C$, $X$, and $H$ be topological spaces with $H$ Hausdorff. Let $F:H\times C \to X$ be continuous.  The claim is that the induced function $\Phi:H\to [C,X]$ is continuous, where $[C,X]$ has the compact-open topology.  For an open subset $U$ of $X$, for a compact subset $K$ of $C$, the subset $(H\times K)\cap \Phi^{-1}(X\setminus U)$ is a closed subset of $H\times K$, hence it is proper over $H$.  So it has closed image in $H$, and the complement of the image is open.

Comment: I'd expect there to be a Tate twist at least. If $k=0$ you get a map from $H_0(H_\beta)=\mathbf Q(0)$ to $H_2(X)$, which has weight $-2$.

Comment: @DanPetersen.  You are correct, there should be a Tate twist.  I will add it now.

Comment: Is this mixed hodge structure constructed by actually making a simplicial scheme (which?) whose cohomology groups are the homotopy groups of the original $X$?

Comment: @VivekShende.  "Is this mixed hodge structure constructed by actually making a simplicial scheme ..."  Whether it *can* be made that way, I do not believe that is how Morgan first constructed these mixed Hodge structures.  Morgan uses a single log resolution and an algebraic construction (basically by spectral sequences) of the rational homotopy type of the open stratum in terms of those of the (projective, smooth) boundary strata.  Deligne proved that this spectral sequence respects mixed Hodge structures.  Morgan checks that is also respects Sullivan minimal models . . .

Comment: . . . This reduces to the smooth, projective case.  In that case, the Sullivan minimal model of the De Rham complex agrees with the Sullivan minimal model of the De Rham cohomology (with zero differentials).  Since the Sullivan minimal model of a dga is (roughly) a multilinear algebra operation on the dga, the work is to check that these multilinear operations respect the weight and Hodge filtrations.

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat No, unfortunately I have not found an answer to this question.